# Documentation for stringFormat in jqChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, string-formatting, jqchart

Is there some kind of documentation for the way `stringFormat` works in jqChart? I haven't found any on their website, not even a hint.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Just found the docs myself: http://www.jqchart.com/documentation/userguide/default.aspx#!LabelsFormatting